# Installed 2x8 (DDR4-2666) DDR4 GB RAM, However American Megatrends shows: Total Memory: 8192MB (DDR4-2133)

Tags: memory, motherboard, desktop-computer, desktop-customization, ramdisk

I have created a custom build and I installed 2x8GB DDR4-2666 RAM. However American Megatrends shows that the total memory of the PC is 8192 DDR4-2133.

My motherboard is ASUS MAXIMUS HERO IX and my RAMs are HuperX Fury Black. At first I installed them on the grey slots **(where getting that total memory of the PC is 8192 DDR4-2133)** then I tried on the black ones slots, however even the screen doesn't turn on. On the grey ones shows that.

An ideas how to fix that?

Answer (score -1):

At first - try to reset your BIOS. I had same problem earlier with DDR3. Second you can refer to manual for you motherboard about RAM slots usage.
At last you can try to find your memory in this [list](http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/LGA1151/MAXIMUS_IX_HERO/MAXIMUS-IX-HERO_Z270-6L_memory_QVL.pdf) - so you can be sure that it supported.

Comment: I checked on the list and it is supported. I have HX426c15FBK2/16

Comment: @ChristosMichael have you tried to reset your BIOS? And are you sure that both planks are working? If your system see only one of them, you can check that.

Comment: I removed again RAMs and put i back and then was showing the correct total of RAM. Appreciate your response and thank you